# How to get specific data uid/uuid from Firebase

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to android. i need help to get uid from firebase. Let's say I have 2 data in my database, and I want to find the 2nd data uid.

[image]

i want to get the data in specific uid FROM Firebase

Comment: uid, is your user id? Do you using firebase auth?

Comment: Check my answer

Comment: What is the "second data"? How do you generate that `393a2 ... 92d07` id? Please also responde with @AlexMamo

Answer (score 0):

If `uid/uuid` is your **UserId** then after login you can use like this:

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("groups").child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getuid()).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                        //Your data is here
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DatabaseReference mUsersDatabase;
//for getting groups data
mGroupsDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("groups");

//add listener for getting uid or key
mUserDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) 
        {
                dataSnapshot.getKey();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

**For getting current user uid**

```
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
String mCurrentUserId;

mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
mCurrentUserId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
```

Hope it works for you!!